# Can't get to Internet although it says I am connected to internet

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. After wiping my C drive clean and reinstalling it, I can't find a way to get to Explorer or any other internet site. Internet Explorer is nowhere to be found! Can anyone help me with this? I am a novice at fixing problems. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to open Internet Explorer (if the link has gone)

1. <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type:

   ```
    iexplore
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Once running, right-click Internet Explorer and click Pin to Task bar, or pin to Start Menu

Comment: @LeeTaylor...This will not work for me. When I do this, it brings up about 90 iexplorer items. I tried pinning several of them to my task bar, but they will not open. The screen just flashes quickly and goes back to the list. Am I going to have to wipe the hard drive clean and start over?

Comment: @Lewis It sounds like you have a bigger problem that just missing the icon for IE. You **may** have a virus/malware infection, for example.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I guess I'll take it to an expert and have it checked out. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Lewis Are you holding the Windows key and pressing R at the same time? It just sounds to me like you are opening the start menu and searching for iexplore